# Ruby on Rails acts_as_votable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-votable

I am trying to create a voting system using **acts_as_votable** gem in Rails 4. I have three nominees to be voted from and I want a voter to choose from any of those three and vote only one `nominee.acts_as_votable` gem allows voter to vote multiple nominees. How do I restrict to only one nominee?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep track of the nominees you can add a before_action in your controller that checks if the current_user has already cast his vote.  If so, flash an error and redirect them etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a `before_action` callback to check if `current_user` has already voted or not only before the `vote` action is called.
For example

```
before_action: :check_if_voted, only: :vote

def check_if_voted
  if current_user.voted_for?(@nominee1) || current_user.voted_for?(@nominee2) || current_user.voted_for?(@nominee3)
    flash[:notice] = "You have cast your vote already."
  end
end
```

And I believe you are using radio button in you form.